# How do you get manure to make farms?

Tags: dont-starve

In the game you can build your own farm plots, but you need manure for it (poo).
How do you obtain this important resource?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can obtain manure either from feeding flowers to pig men, or more reliably from finding a herd of [Beefalo](http://www.dontstarvegame.com/blog/wilsons-field-notes-beefalo/), who produce it all the time.

Comment: Any fruit or vegetable works, not just flowers...